ROS2 - Message communcation used protocol
Which is the sharing used protocol by ROS2 Humble with Cyclone DDS when we publish a message on the ROS2 Network? From what I comprehended it should be multicast. But I don't know if multicast is used just for the discovery of possible nodes or also for message-sharing by publishers/subscribers.
Thanks.
